# Show most basic type declaration of nested typedefs in c++

Tags: c++, typedef

When reading someone else's code, is there an easy way to unfold the underlying types of a nested typedef, except for going through all headers, searching for the respective definitions?

E.g. today I encountered

`auto* p = new A<B::C>();`

where B::C is defined in some header as

```
template <typename T>
class B: public BBase {
    typedef B< D<E, E> > C;
}
```

and D and E are defined somewhere else. C

Can I somehow display that p is actually `A<B<D<E, E>>>`?

Comment: You can use `typeid(T).name()`. It gives you a nice readable type declaration in Visual C++. With g++ compiler you have to use g++-specific functionality to demangle the somewhat cryptic result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative if you don't want to demangle `typeid` names is:

```
template<typename> struct TC;
```

Then put `TC<A<B::C>> a;` somewhere and you'll get a compiler error with the full deduced type in it.

For example:

```
template<typename> struct TC;

template<typename> using A = int;
using B = A<float>;

int main()
{
    TC<B> a;
}
```

GCC outputs:

> main.cpp:8:11: error: aggregate `TC<int> a` has incomplete type and cannot be defined

As you can see, `B` was substituted for `A<float>`, which was substituted for `int` in the compiler error.

Comment: Awesome. While it feels wrong at first to use a compiler error message, it  removes the need to actually run any code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeid(T).name()`. It gives you a nice readable type declaration in Visual C++. With g++ compiler you have to use g++-specific functionality to demangle the somewhat cryptic result.

In order to use `typeid` you must include the `<typeinfo>` header.

The g++ name demangling function is [`abi::__cxa_demangle` from the g++ `<cxxabi.h>` header](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html).

---

Example (I had to fix various details of your alleged declarations):

```
template< class > struct A {};

template<class, class> struct D {};

struct E {};

struct BBase {};

template<class>
class B: public BBase
{
public:
    using C = B< D<E, E> >;
};

#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

#ifdef __GNUC__
#   include <cxxabi.h>

    auto demangled( char const* name )
        -> string
    {
        int status = 0;
        char* realname = abi::__cxa_demangle( name, 0, 0, &status );
        string result = realname;
        free( realname );
        return result;
    }

#else
#   include <sstream>

    auto demangled( char const* name )
        -> string
    {
        // Possibly remove all instances of "struct ", "class " and "enum "
        return name;
    }

#endif

#include <iostream>
auto main() -> int
{
    auto* p = new A<B<int>::C>();
    (void) p;  // unused
    cout << demangled( typeid( p ).name() ) << endl;
}
```

Output with g++:

```
A<B<D<E, E> > >*
```

---

An alternative is the [trick presented by TartanLlama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34920865/464581), of using the relevant type in an undefined template:

```
template<class> class Incomplete;

auto main() -> int
{
    Incomplete< A<B<int>::C> > x;
}
```

which with g++ generates the error message:

```
ar.cpp:24:36: error: aggregate 'Incomplete<A<B<D<E, E> > > > x' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
        Incomplete< A<B<int>::C> > x;
                                   ^
```

Comment: Pretty good! I added `template<typename T> void print_type(T p){ cout << demangled( typeid( p ).name() ) << endl; }` which makes usage as easy as `print_type(p);`

Answer (score 0):

Those are the options that comes to my mind:

1) Debug printing, you can temporary add typeid(E) etc, but requires compiling and running, so not just reading the code.

2) Using an IDE like visual studio, qt creator etc, should be able to show you the actual typedefs/defines when hovering with the mouse on any usage of the typedef/defines.

3) Using text editors, many text editor might allow to have plugins to speed up the search and to jump from symbol to symbol to quickly find were they are defined.

So final answer I think by just looking at the code there is no way to know that, and that is actually a bit of a problem coming with the defines, it obfuscates the code a little.

Comment: 1b) With `template <typename> struct debug_type;` writting `debug_type<A<B::C>>{};` gives error at compile type where most compiler expand type.

Comment: Thanks. I was using number 3, but for nested types it distracts me. And I haven't found the IDE to replace vim yet.

Answer (score 0):

on gcc/clang:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>
#include <typeinfo>

std::string demangle(const char* mangled_name)
{
    using namespace std;

    size_t len = 0;
    int stat = 0;

    struct deleter {
        void operator()(const char* p) const {
            if (p) {
                auto p1 = const_cast<char*>(p);
                free(p1);
            }
        }
    };
    using ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<const char, deleter>;
    auto pname = ptr_type(abi::__cxa_demangle(mangled_name,
                                              nullptr,
                                              &len,
                                              &stat),
                          deleter());

    if (stat)
    {
        switch(stat) {
            case -1:
                throw std::bad_alloc();
                break;
            case -2:
                throw std::logic_error("invalid name: "s + mangled_name);
                break;
            case -3:
                throw std::invalid_argument("demangle");
            default:
                throw std::logic_error("unknown error code "s + to_string(stat));
        }
    }

    return string(pname.get(), len);
}

template<class X, class Y> struct D {};
struct E {};

template <typename T>
struct B {
    typedef B< D<E, E> > C;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << demangle(typeid(B<int>::C).name()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

no doubt windows will have a similar means of detangling a name.

expected output:

```
B<D<E, E> >
```